# Knitr - problems on encoding certain portuguese characters (windows10)

Tags: r, encoding, knitr

I am working on automatic generation of some reports involving characters like "ç","ã","á" and Rstudio returns characters like §,Ã³,Ã£ instead. Among other things, I've tried: to use options(encoding = "UTF8"), to do not import data from excel (since I've learned excel doesn't handle special characters very well and it can affect on how RStudio will deal with those chars).

ps: R compiles everything just fine, I don't receive any message of error.

ps2:I have the latest version of R and knitr.

ps3: funny thing is that the encoding error occurs specifically with what I type directly in the markdown file. Example:

Suppose I have:

`c<- "Ação"`

And in my Rmd file I write "Ação" and call "c" in a chunk.
When compiled I get this:

aÃ§Ã£o Ação

#### **Update**

I found that it happens only when I use `rmarkdown::render` (note that setting `encoding = "UTF8"` doesn't help). Apparently or I solve the encoding issue or I'll have to generate reports one by one, because if I use the "Knit" button on the toolbar the report comes out fine.

#### **Update²**

Well, I got over the problem, but oddly enough, I don't know exactly how.
I noticed that using `knit2html('myfile.Rmd',encoding = 'UTF-8',force_v1 = TRUE)` returned a report free from encoding problems, but where I wrote #(blablabla) I had to add a space between the hashtag and the text because looks like the `knit2html` just recognize hashtag as a command to generate bigger words if there is a space between the symbol and the text.

From there everything was running well and I decided to check if I could create a loop with `knit2html` and finally get my reports automatically generated, before doing so I noticed in my project directory two files that weren't there before: `myfile.utf8.md` and `myfile.knit.md`. Out of curiosity I tried running again the loop with  `rmarkdown::render`setting `encoding = "UTF8"` and this time simply worked.

Yihui, do you know anything about this dark magic? What on the earth happened?

Comment: I don't know. `rmarkdown::render(encoding = 'UTF-8')` should work if your Rmd file was really saved with the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Ah, now it's working beautifully, this is what matters. I may try to understand what happened on the free time.